# Plot based on dependent selection

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have a data frame book3. It has three column Region, Country and Rating.

```
Region<- c("Americas", "Asia Pacific","Asia Pacific", "EMEA", "EMEA")
Country<- c("Mexico", "China","India", "Germany", "Spain" )
Rating<- c(5,3,3,2,4)
book3<- data.frame(Region, Country, Rating)
```

I want to achieve when i select from drop-down  "Americas" Region,  it should only display Mexico and when i select Asia Pacific it should display China and India and for EMEA it should display Germany and Spain.

In brief I want to create dependent drop down of Region and Country. The Country drop down should display the country based on the Region.

It should be able to generate the plot as well based on the rating column

I have my code in ui.R and server.R please suggest something

Ui.R

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Test Dashboard "),
 sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
 uiOutput("data1"),   ## uiOutput - gets the UI from the server
 uiOutput("data2")
 ),    
mainPanel()   
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  Region<- c("Americas", "Asia Pacific","Asia Pacific", "EMEA", "EMEA")
 Country<- c("Mexico", "China","India", "Germany", "Spain" )
Rating<- c(5,3,3,2,4)
  book3<- data.frame(Region, Country, Rating, stringsAsFactors = F)
output$data1 <- renderUI({
 selectInput("data1", "Select Region", choices = c(book3$Region))
 })

output$data2 <- renderUI({

selectInput("data2", "select Country", choices = c(book3$Country))
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy and you are almost there:

```
library(shiny)
test <- "http://www.score11.de"
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test Dashboard "),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("data1"),   ## uiOutput - gets the UI from the server
      uiOutput("data2")
    ),    
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))   
  ))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  Region<- c("Americas", "Asia Pacific","Asia Pacific", "EMEA", "EMEA")
  Country<- c("Mexico", "China","India", "Germany", "Spain" )
  Rating<- c(5,3,3,2,4)
  book3<- data.frame(Region, Country, Rating, stringsAsFactors = F)
  output$data1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("data1", "Select Region", choices = c(book3$Region))
  })

  output$data2 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("data2", "select Country", choices = book3[which(book3$Region == input$data1),]$Country)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    barplot(mean(book3[which(book3$Country == input$data2),]$Rating), ylim=c(0,10), xlim=c(0,2), width=0.5)
  })


})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Since I do not know your final application the plot title depends on the Rating column.

Comment: Thank you. I want that,  it should show average rating based on selection in BarPlot. i used book3$rating  using barplot function but it does not plot.

Comment: Average rating? You only have one observation per country?

Comment: This works for me: `barplot(book3[which(book3$Country == input$data2),]$Rating, ylim=c(0,10))`.

Comment: There are many observation for each country, I want to average them and create the plot(barplot) of the same

Comment: So the barplot will show only one bar. I changed the code in the answer.

Comment: It is working but not changing the data values when i change the selection.

Comment: Then you might have a semantic error somewhere. The above code works for me and the plot changes when I change the region or the country (except for China and India since their Rating value is the same).

Comment: This works fine. If i want to add Rating1 and Rating2, will the approach be fine?

Comment: This is very vague. Dont kno what you mean exactly but it should work....